# (Unity Web) How to show Debug.Log in browser inspector rather then '~/Library/Logs/Unity'?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity-web-player

I wonder how to show Debug.Log in browser inspector rather then '~/Library/Logs/Unity'. Since i am  developing a multi-player game, now when I open two browsers, the logs are displayed in the same log file, all in a mess!

btw, I see there is an option 'script debugging' in build settings but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

the way I've done this is to make a call out from Unity to the browser

(have a look at http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebPlayerandbrowsercommunication.html)

So in my Unity c# script I call

```
Application.ExternalCall( "BrowserLog", "my log message" );
```

Ad in my host page javascript I have a function

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
<!--
function BrowserLog( msg)
{
    // logthe message
    console.log( msg);
}
-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Garrett's answer works fine.
As an improvement you can also code like this avoiding the extra javascript function:

```
Application.ExternalCall( "console.log", "my log message" );
```